# Sharing Internet connection on a virtual machine

Tags: windows-xp, networking, virtualbox, proxy, internet-connection

So I'm running VirtualBox and have Linux running on there.  However, I don't have any Internet access on the virtual machine.  I believe this is why: The host machine is Windows XP, and it's configured to use a proxy server.  The proxy server demands NT credentials, so the machine has to be logged on to the domain.  Since the network adapter on XP and the VirtualBox network adapter are bridged, the network sees the Linux machine as a real computer.  I cannot logon to the NT domain with the Linux computer.

Here's what I think I need: A proxy server that can run on Windows XP, and then route all web requests to another proxy server, while at the same time "adding on" the NT domain credentials to the request.  Does anyone know if such a thing exists?

I know it would be "dangerous" to run, as anyone who could access my proxy server could "become me" on the domain, but I'd guess I could restrict proxy traffic to only the IP on the Linux machine or just bind the proxy server to the virtual network adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're interested in is internet access on the virtual machine, you could consider choosing NAT instead of Bridged Adapter for the VM. Is that not an option for some reason not mentioned in your question?

You can change the adapter binding for each virtual machine under the Network settings section.

Comment: Yea, NAT is actually the default - however, it still doesn't work.  I believe it's because VirtualBox itself does not seem to send outgoing traffic through the configured proxy.  I wonder if there's a way to configure VirtualBox to use a proxy for guest network traffic.

Comment: So there's a "Proxy Server" tab in VirtualBox configuration, but it appears to be only used for internal VirtualBox networking such as checking for new versions and downloading extensions.  It will not route guest traffic through that proxy server.  I would still need to configure the guest OS to use a proxy server which I'm trying to avoid doing.

Answer (score 0):

YOU SAY : "A proxy server that can run on Windows XP, and then route all web requests to another proxy server, while at the same time "adding on" the NT domain credentials to the request. Does anyone know if such a thing exists?"

Try this : http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/

Configure it : http://wingloon.com/2010/08/16/install-and-configure-ntlmaps-to-access-isa-server/

However I have not used it specifically with Virtual Box, just to perform NTLM authentication using Python scripts.

Hope it helps.